# How to mitigate Win32 problem with import module?

Tags: python, winapi

I am trying to write a df to a Word document by the following code:

```
import win32api
import win32
# data frame
wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
wordApp.Visible = False
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(os.getcwd()+'\\template.docx')
rng = doc.Bookmarks("PUTTABLEHERE").Range

# creating Table 
# add one more row in table at word because you want to add column names as header
Table=rng.Tables.Add(rng,NumRows=df.shape[0]+1,NumColumns=df.shape[1])

    for col in range(df.shape[1]):        
        # Writing column names 
        Table.Cell(1,col+1).Range.Text=str(df.columns[col]) 
        for row in range(df.shape[0]):
            # writing each value of data frame 
            Table.Cell(row+1+1,col+1).Range.Text=str(df.iloc[row,col])
```

I however get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-b3ea6c24ddfe> in <module>
      1 # data frame
----> 2 wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
      3 wordApp.Visible = False
      4 doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(os.getcwd()+'\\template.docx')
      5 rng = doc.Bookmarks("PUTTABLEHERE").Range

AttributeError: module 'win32' has no attribute 'gencache'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `win32` defined?

Comment: @Axe319 , thanks, edited, however still the same error..

Comment: You probably intended to use `import win32com.client as win32`.